# WPF Report Generation

Tags: c#, wpf, report

Direct question: Which is the best report generation for WPF? (itext, microsoft report, crystal report, etc).

I need to create a static report (i.e: fixed size). I will fill some field and add some images. So far, I am considering using itext to fill a Pdf Form

Comment: I had used Microsoft Report Builder to build reports (rdl) and Microsoft ReportViewer control to display/export them to various formats. Its very easy to use and the ReportViewer nicely integrates with WPF using WindowsFormsHost.

Comment: How to achieve report generation using itextsharp?